# Delete User Input from the Terminal in C

Tags: c, input, output, echo

I'm working on a program for Windows and Linux, coding it in C, and I want the program to get input from a user, show it until it finished (i.e. pressed 'enter'), then un-display what the user entered, finally re-displaying it with a time stamp.

It should look like this:

(Before user hits enter)

`Enter a string: abcde`

(Then after inputting the string "abcde")

`|19:53| User: abcde`

Currently what the program does is:

`Enter a string: abcde`

`|19:53| User: abcde`

Without the row of the input dissappearing.

Comment: Why the `c++` tag?

Comment: You can use `fgets()` or `gets()` to read string until enter

Comment: @senoron `gets()` is not part of the standard C library anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's hard. You have to go up one line to clear it. On Linux, you can use ANSI escape codes like `"\033[A"` to go up one line. There is no C standard way to do it.

If you print something and you are on the same line, use `"\b"` to backspace one character. From then, you can use white space to clear the inputs.